# Regex para remover HTML Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Tenho um trecho de HTML em que eu extraio algumas informações. Porém em um desses HTML está vindo o code `&#43` no meio, que significa o sinal `+`.
Tentei algumas formas mas nada de remover esse caractere.

Há alguma ideia de como tirar em específico os HTML code? 
Hoje acontece isso mas pode ter problemas com outros também, exemplo sinal de `-`.

O que eu já tentei:

```
string texto = "<td>Para maiores informações consulte: &#43; informações</td>";
string novoTexto = Regex.Replace(texto, "[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Por que remover? Não seria melhor simplesmente fazer o decode? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19692654

Comment: opa valeu hkotsubo, tinha esquecido dessa possibilidade! Funcionou aqui pra mim, se vc quiser postar como resposta, eu deixo como resolvido

Comment: Demorei, mas coloquei uma resposta :-)

Comment: valeu, agradeço seu tempo em ter respondido :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um [*HTML Entity*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) é uma informação perfeitamente válida em um HTML e não há motivo para removê-lo.

O que você pode fazer é o *decode* dele, usando [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) (disponível no namespace [`System.Web`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=netframework-4.7.2)), ou [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads) (disponível no namespace [`System.Net`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net?view=netframework-4.7.2)):

```
string texto = "<td>Para maiores informações consulte: &#43; informações</td>";
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(texto));
Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(texto));
```

Ambos produzem o mesmo resultado:

```
<td>Para maiores informações consulte: + informações</td>
```

---

Mas se quiser **remover** os *HTML Entities* (e não substituí-los pelos caracteres equivalentes), então basta usar:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(texto, "&[^;]+;", string.Empty));
```

A regex contém o caractere `&` no início e o `;` no final. Entre eles, há:

- `[^;]`: o `[^` cria uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), ou seja, este trecho representa qualquer caractere que não esteja dentro dos colchetes. Portanto, este trecho significa "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `;`"
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências"

Portanto, a regex significa: o caractere `&`, seguido de um ou mais caracteres que não sejam `;`, seguido de `;`. Com isso, todos os *HTML Entities* são eliminados. A saída é:

```
<td>Para maiores informações consulte:  informações</td>
```

---

Apenas para explicar porque sua regex não funcionou.

`[;\\/:*?\"<>|&']`: os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que corresponde a qualquer caractere entre os colchetes. Portanto, esta regex significa "o caractere `;`, **ou** o caractere `\`, **ou** o caractere `/`, **ou** o `:` etc...". O detalhe é que toda essa expressão corresponde a **apenas um caractere** (e este pode ser qualquer um dos que estão indicados).

Portanto, esta regex só elimina esses caracteres. No caso do *HTML Entity*, somente o `&` e o `;` são eliminados, mas os números e o `#` não.

Comment: Eu gosto de ler suas respostas sobre Regex. Se você escrever ou já tiver escrito algo sobre o assunto me passa nome do livro que eu compro.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Obrigado! Já escrevi um livro, mas não é sobre regex (veja no meu perfil, é sobre um assunto que não aparecem tantas perguntas, se comparado com regex...). Mas agradeço pelo comentário, é sinal que meus estudos estão valendo a pena :-)